# Given two points on a curve, how can I calculate rotation degree of the curve to get from one point to another?

Tags: animation, mathematics

Given the image below, I am trying to find the degrees I need to rotate the curve itself, to get A (x1, y1) to point B (x2, y2). I need this rotation to animate a circle along a path for the web (writing the animations in code).

[image]

Comment: What format do you have the coordinates and circle in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must know the centerpoint of the circle. Otherwise there's infinite number of possible circles common for A and B.

Think the points as complex numbers A=x1+iY1, B=x2+iY2. In the same way let the centerpoint of the circle be C=x3+iy3

radius B-C = (A-C)exp(iD) where D=the needed rotation from A to B in radians. Thus you calculate (B-C)/(A-C), convert the result to polar form and get the needed angle as the angle of the polar presentation. The result is seen as CCW direction.

**No actual division is needed.** As well you convert A-C and B-C both to polar form and subtract the angles to get the difference.

Comment: I find it simpler to use {sin, cos} but ok

Comment: it's subjectively simpler, but the final calculation is the same. Complex numbers do not need help drawings which easily introduce invalid assumptions of the directions and angle sizes.

Comment: I agree but the reason i use sin, cos is that i find sin cos more useful in other circumstances so i dont need to carry around 2 separate notations